# Recursive LinkedList Insert Method

Tags: python, linked-list, insert

I am trying to create an Insert method which takes a parameter (position) and inserts a Node into a linkedlist at that given position. Thus, the new value would be the value of the parameter (val) and then the next node would take the original value and so forth. This also needs to utilize recursion.

I am currently trying to mess around with the conditionals and first say that if our index matches our desired position, we can set a new_node to our current node and then set our current node to a Node with our desired value. Then our next node can take the value of current node. After that, I have a conditional where if our index is greater, I set the next node to our current node.
I am currently not seeing the insertion change the values in the linkedlist and also getting an infinite loop, which I feel like has to do with when we reach the end of the LinkedList, it is not ending properly. I'd appreciate if anyone has any suggestions of how I could go about fixing this or if my logic is just wrong.

```
    def insert(self, val, position, current=None, index=0, new_node=None):
    if self._head is None:
        self._head = Node(val)
        return
    if current is None:
        current = self._head
    if position > index and current.next is None:
        current.next = Node(val)
        return
    if position == index and current is not None:
        new_node = current.next
        self._head = Node(val)
    if position > index and current is not None:
        new_node = current.next
        self._head = current
    if current is None:
        return
    self.insert(val, position, current.next, index + 1)
```

Comment: What do `position` and `index` represent?  It seems like you should either be adding to `position` or subtracting from `index` as you recurse forward, but instead `position` remains constant (even as you move forward) and `index` moves further away.

Comment: Show code and other textual information as properly formatted text in the question, not as comment, image or external link.

Comment: Oh my bad, I think I fixed it. But responding to Samwise, position is the element that we want to insert the new node. I created a parameter index(which might not even be necessary) to track which index we are at of the linked list. How come we would want to add to position?

Comment: Ah, maybe I had it backwards.  The way I'd probably do it would be to just have one parameter and subtract from it as you iterate forward, rather than having two and trying to have one count up to the other.  It'd give you less to keep track of.

Answer (score 0):

This case seems wrong:

```
    if position == index and current is not None:
        new_node = current.next
        self._head = Node(val)
```

This would be the point where you'd want to insert the new node at `current`.  Instead, you set a `new_node` variable (which does nothing, because you don't do anything else with it), and then you create a new `self._head` (which effectively deletes the rest of the list).

Your recursion never stops because on each recursion you increment `index`, but your base case is based on `position > index`:

```
    # checking that we're at the end of the list
    # AND position is ahead of index
    if position > index and current.next is None:
        current.next = Node(val)
        return
```

```
    self.insert(val, position, current.next, index + 1)
    # next moves forward, index moves forward
```

Recursion should always move you closer to your base case, which means that either `position` should be increasing or `index` should be decreasing, but instead `index` is increasing while `position` stays the same, which means it's never possible to satisfy your base case.

I might write the function like this, with fewer parameters and only two base cases:

```
def insert(self, val, index=0, current=None):
    if current is None:
        current = self._head
    if index <= 0 or self._head is None:
        # Insert new val as head.
        new_node = Node(val)
        new_node.next = self._head
        self._head = new_node
    elif index == 1 or current.next is None:
        # Insert new val as current.next.
        new_node = Node(val)
        new_node.next = current.next
        current.next = new_node
    else:
        # Move down the list.
        self.insert(val, index - 1, current.next)
```

In this implementation, `index` represents the position relative to `current` where we want to insert the new node, i.e. if `index == 0` we want the new node to take the place of `current`, and if `index == 1` we want the new node to take the place of `current.next`.

Our first base case checks for `index == 0` on the initial call, in which case we want to replace `self._head`.  The next base case checks for `index == 1`, in which case we want to replace `current.next`.  Note that if `current != self._head` and `index == 0` we'd be stuck because we don't have a pointer to the *previous* node in order to be able to replace `current` in the list, so that's why we want to do the `current.next` insertion at `index == 1`, before we advance to the next node.

In both base cases we also have an `or` that covers the case where we're at the end of the list (including the case where the list is empty) and it doesn't make sense to iterate forward regardless of what `index` is.

When we recurse, we move `current` forward by one spot, and decrement `index` by one, since we're one position closer to the desired location.  Eventually `index` will reach 1, or we'll reach the end of the list, at which point we're done and we stop recursing.

Comment: I think that makes sense to me. Recursion is something that is sort of hard to visualize for me but I think I figured how to make the method with my own implementation where I also took index as you did and decreased it by 1 for each iteration. I was previously under the impression that I needed to check different ranges where index was not 0. One thing that I notice is that you don't have any return statements, is that fine? The way I recursively call is how you did similarly, but I was told that normally you want to return the recursive call? Thanks for thorough advice though!

Comment: In a recursive function that returns a value, it's important to make sure to return the result of your recursive call, but this function returns `None` so the only potential purpose of a `return` would be to end the control flow early (and the way I've structured my `if/elif/else` that's not necessary).

Comment: If you wanted the `insert` method to return the node that was added, you'd add `return new_node` to the base cases where a `new_node` is created, and `return self.insert(...)` at the end so that the result of the recursive call is returned.